Testing provider in flutter which depends on Firebase
I am trying the following test:
@GenerateMocks([Tour])
void main() {
  group('TripProvider', () {
    test('add Trip', () async {
      final mockTrip = MockTour();
      TripProvider provider = TripProvider();

      when(provider.addTrip(
        mockTrip.name,
        mockTrip.startDate,
        mockTrip.endDate,
        mockTrip.budget,
        mockTrip.currency,
        mockTrip.type,
        mockTrip.locations,
        mockTrip.members,
      )).thenAnswer((_) async => mockTrip);
    });
  });
}

TripProvider uses TripRepository which in turn uses Firebase. Now when I try to run the tests I am getting the following error:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

I wrote a few other tests which doesn't depend on any api call or firebase which worked fine.
